# jQuery set html() value

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectAddress" name="select2" size="4" multiple="multiple">
    <option>address 1</option>
    <option>address 2</option>
    <option>address3, some city, uk</option>
    <option>address4, some city, uk</option>
    <option>address4, some city, uk</option>
</select>

<p id="chosenAddress01" class="renderedYellowBox">result in here</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".selectAddress").dblclick(function() {
var address = [];
    $('.selectAddress option:selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
       address[i] = $(selected).text(); 
    });
    //alert(address);

    $('#chosenAddress01').html(address);
    });
```

**Problem**

I'm trying to get the selected value of the address option to populate the p tag on dblclick() of the address

If I use the alert box to check the result, the correct result comes thru. But trying to get the result into the p tag returns nothing.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to turn it into a string first, like this:

```
$('#chosenAddress01').html(address.join(', '));
```

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) [treats an array differently,](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/manipulation.js#L229) so best to explicitly make it a string since that's what you're after.  The reason `alert()` works is there's an implicit `.toString()` going on there.

Answer (score 3):

1. You're a brave man to use "dblclick"
2. You'll want to join the array:

   $('#chosenAddress01').html(address.join(' '));

Comment: Thanks. Just finding my feet with jQuery at the moment, and discovering the power, and nuances of it. What's the issues related with dblClick()?

Comment: Well browsers just don't do a very good job with "dblclick" and "click".  It *might* work out for you, but it makes me a little nervous because `<option>` elements have some native behavior on the "click" event already.

Answer (score 1):

Address is an array, did you try to convert into a string?